# my copy to clipboard code in JavaScript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, function, copy, clipboard, copy-paste

as you would have guessed from my question and as you will interpret by looking at my code , im a beginner. this is the first real application i tried to write in javascript and i would love to understand why it doesn't work?

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var text = document.getElementById("text");
function button() {
 text.select();
 text.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); 
navigator.clipboard.writeText(text.value);
alert("you copied this text");
}
```

**button is a onclick event in html and text is an input in html.**
thank you very much

Comment: please add all your code ;-)

Comment: There is some documentation for the new `clipboard` API. [But note:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard) "The navigator.clipboard API is a recent addition to the specification and may not be fully implemented in all browsers. This article describes some limitations, but be sure to review the compatibility tables for each method before using them to ensure that the API supports your needs."

Comment: Is the function `button` actually called? Also, `writeText` returns a `Promise`, so the `alert` call does not actually tell you if the clipboard was written to. What browser are you using, and version? The [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) is still pretty new.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, the `writeText` is a promise, but also the `Clipboard API` needs permision. Check this if the permission is granted or not

```js
function myFunction() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myText");

  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value).then(function() {
    alert("Copied to clipboard successfully!");
  }, function(error) {
    alert("ERROR:\n"+error);
  });;
}

async function CheckPermission(){
  const readPerm = await navigator.permissions.query({name: 'clipboard-read', allowWithoutGesture: false });
  
  const writePerm = await navigator.permissions.query({name: 'clipboard-write', allowWithoutGesture: false });
  
  // Will be 'granted', 'denied' or 'prompt':
  alert('Read: '+readPerm.state+'\nWrite: '+writePerm.state);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="ASDF" id="myText">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button><br><br>
<button onclick="CheckPermission()">Check Permission</button>
```

If so, need to ask permission. More info [here](https://web.dev/async-clipboard/).

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if i should write this as an answer or what. but anyways i rewrote the code and it ended up like this :

```
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

function buttonholder() {
text.select();
text.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
navigator.clipboard.writeText(text.value);
}
button.addEventListener("click",buttonholder);
```

thank you everyone that replied.
its working fine. i don't know why the first code didn't work but well the second code is much better than the last one
again thanks for helping. some of your references made me think of addEventListener.