# Copy to clipboard not working for devices other than own in react

Tags: reactjs, clipboard

I'm trying to incorporate a copy to clipboard feature in my web app and I have this line of code:

```
<button className="btn btn-outline" onClick={function(e){ navigator.clipboard.writeText(project.goal)
    .then(() => {
        alert('Text copied to clipboard!')
    })
    .catch(() => {
        alert("Something went wrong!")
    });
}}
    >
    Copy to Clipboard
</button>
```

This works for me when I test it out using my own computer which is running the web app, but when I connect to the server using another machine like my phone, the copy to clipboard doesn't work. Does anyone know why and how I can fix this?

Comment: Make sure you're using https. Otherwise clipboard may not be availalble.

Comment: Maybe a [permission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69934424/6273711) issue?